# Error in Android studio gradle build

Tags: android-studio

While building gradle i got error like

> Error:Error:line (29)Supplied String module notation
>   'com.com_.android.volley' is invalid. Example notations:
>   'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2',
>   'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

My app/build.gradle code

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please can you use markdown formatting to make errors and code clearer. For example fomat the error text you get above and also, instead of showing screenshots of code, include the code in your question.

Comment: have a look [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/volley-a-networking-library-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

Add version of volley artifact in build.gradle file.

```
 compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```